# How do i restore the default ubuntu sound effects

Tags: sound

How do Reinstall default ubuntu sound effect, when like the volume when it goes bloop for example when i turn the volume up?

Because i Changed my settings accidentally but i don't know how to return it back to default.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, go to System Settings, and click on sound.  Once the Window open, click on the Sound Effects Tab, and choose Default.

[image]

Added info:

Use GConf-Editor to find out if sound is enabled.  You can type conf in dash, and click on configuration editor.  If its not installed, then, just click [**Install GConf-Editor** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor/).  See image below.

[image]

Comment: done but that did NOT fix it

Comment: but i guess il live withotu the bloop of when i turn my volume up

Comment: See if what I added can help you.

Comment: i cant see the rest look: http://i1118.photobucket.com/albums/k613/samgabbay/Screenshotfrom2013-06-13125600.png

Comment: I can research some more, and get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: PLEASE DO I NEED THIS FIXED ASAP

Comment: Try dconf-editor, and see if sound is active. Take a [look](http://s1296.photobucket.com/user/joetjo/media/2013-06-13_2014_zpsf061a03d.png.html?sort=3&o=0).

Comment: it is mitch its active

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/05/how-to-turn-off-or-change-login-sound.html) see if it helps.

Comment: do i follow what it says

Comment: Yes, its worth a try.

Comment: done i enabled it now what next do i reboot?

Comment: yeah, try it out.

Comment: it worked hearing the login sound but when i press the volume up key on my keyboard it dont hear when it does the sound when it goes up that bloop sound

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9232/discussion-between-mitch-and-samgabbay)